# detecting two simultaneous keys in pyglet (python)

Tags: python, keyboard, pyglet

I wanted to know how to detect when two keys are simultaneously pressed using pyglet.
I currently have

```
def on_text_motion(self, motion):
    (dx,dy) = ARROW_KEY_TO_VERSOR[motion]
    self.window.move_dx_dy((dx,dy))
```

But this only gets arrow keys one at a time...
I'd like to distinguish between the combination UP+LEFT
and UP, then LEFT...

Hope I made myself clear
Manu

Comment: Do you get key up, key down notifications?  If so, you have the necessary information.  If not, you need to get that information somehow.  (Then you can distinguish between UP_DOWN, LEFT_DOWN, UP_UP, LEFT_UP (UP/LEFT simultaneously pressed) and UP_DOWN, UP_UP, LEFT_DOWN, LEFT_UP (UP pressed, then LEFT pressed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [pyglet.window.key.KeyStateHandler](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.window.key.KeyStateHandler-class.html):

```
import pyglet

key = pyglet.window.key

win = pyglet.window.Window()
keyboard = key.KeyStateHandler()
win.push_handlers(keyboard)

print keyboard[key.UP] and keyboard[key.LEFT]
```